# XenServer 6.5 - Creating local iso storage/library failed - SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_222

Tags: lvm, xenserver

I was trying to adapt instructions for XenServer 6.2 on how to create a local ISO library to a freshly installed XenServer 6.5 host. However the command ...

```
xe sr-create name-label=LocalIso type=iso device-config:legacy-mode=true device-config:location=/var/iso content-type=iso
```

... fails with the following error code and message ...

```
Error code: SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_222
Error parameters: , Could not mount the directory specified in Device Configuration,
```

An active logical volume is mounted at "/var/iso". So the directory should be accessible.

```
# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-<id>/MGT' [4.00 MB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-<id>/ISO' [32.00 GB] inherit

# df -T
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
[...]
/dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--<id>-ISO
              ext3    33027952    766592  30583640   3% /var/iso
```

Don't know how to go from there, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a tutorial how to do this, with additional information how to create ISO storage on a separate partition:
http://adamscheller.com/server-administration/xenserver-local-iso-storage-new-partition/

Answer (score 0):

You should ssh to your xen and do the following:

```
cd /var/run/sr-mount/<your uuid>
mkdir ISO <or whatever>
xe sr-create name-label=ISO type=iso device-config:location=/var/run/sr-mount/<your uuid>/ISO device-config:legacy_mode=true content-type=iso
```

Then I suggest to winscp to your xen @`cd /var/run/sr-mount/<your uuid>/<your iso>`

Comment: Thanks, but there is no folder named "sr-mount" at "/var/run". There is also no folder "sr-mount" or a folder with my uuid in the whole file system tree...